# Consequences of using Office365 account on iPhone

Tags: email, exchange, iphone

Recently my employer switched the email to Office365. Initially I was able to check my email from my iPhone using IMAP. However recently this stopped working and I am not sure why (I didn't change any settings on the phone besides updating iOS).

It seems that one option would be to add the account as Exchange or perhaps Outlook.com using the built-in Mail app. It is my understanding that adding an iPhone to Exchange may allow the deployment of some kind of mobile device management. Is this correct and if so, how can I check what is are the effects of that (for example, wipe the device, deploy some policies, etc).

Related question -- what are the best third-party clients for iOS (besides Outlook) that can access Office365 accounts?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: In my opinion the question does not belong to apple.stackexchange.com, because it  is not entirely related to the Apple ecosystem --  there is MS service (Office365) involved and moreover the specific part - MDM also applies to other mobile operating systems (say Android).

Comment: MDM is based on the account owners rules. There's no "default" MDM controls, just the ones the owners of the email box (which is not you) choose. This doesn't belong on Apple, it needs to be closed because it is about business computer accounts, and the people who can answer the question are the ones signing OPs paychecks.

Comment: Disagree with that too. It is a technical question, not a policy one, especially because it concerns **my own** device, not a company-issued one.

Comment: The reason I recommended it going to apple.stackexchange.com is because the first question is about whether adding an **iPhone** to exchange will force the deployment of MDM. The second is how to identify if MDM is set up on an **iOS** device. The third question is a recommendation on third party mail client for **iOS**. If the intent of this question is not to be focused on iOS then I’d recommend rewording it.

Comment: I would disagree again with the selective reading and will repeat my part of my previous comment "there is MS service (**Office365**) involved and moreover the specific part - **MDM** also applies to other mobile operating systems". If this was an Apple service (iCloud mail) instead of Office365 (**which is even in the title of the question**), indeed, this would be Apple-related question. But now it involves as much Apple products as others.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use IMAP+Basic authentication when you configured your account in Outlook for IOS? If so, as i know, there's a update about it recently:

*Today, we are announcing that, effective October 1, 2022, we will begin to permanently disable Basic Auth in all tenants, regardless of usage, with the exception of SMTP Auth.*

Reference: [Basic Authentication and Exchange Online – September 2021 Update](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-september-2021-update/ba-p/2772210).

If the above is not your issue, please provide more information about your issue:

- Do other users in your organization encounter the same issue?

  Can you add you IMAP account in Outlook for Android?

Comment: About Basic Auth: from what I have read the current version of Mail for iOS supports it. As for Android: don't have one to try. I think that the other users use the web interface only.

Answer (score 0):

> It is my understanding that adding an iPhone to Exchange may allow the deployment of some kind of mobile device management.

It's not mandatory but any organisation with a sensible data loss policy will enforce mobile device management to retain control over data leakage.

> How can I check what is are the effects of that (for example, wipe the device, deploy some policies, etc).

Apple has a page that details MDM [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/deployment/depc0aadd3fe/web). A device with MDM on it can enable your organisation to add/remove/update software and device settings, monitor your compliance with their organisational policies, enforce restrictions (eg. locking timeout and passcodes), restrict apps you can install or use and remotely wipe or lock your device.

**Without trying to sound overly dramatic, it means your company controls your personal phone and you cannot override any decisions that your company makes about your phone.**

Personally, I would refuse to install any MDM on a personal device. If your organisation wants you to access your emails remotely then they need to provide you with a device to do that. That device will still have MDM on it, but it won't matter because it's their phone and not yours.

Comment: Assuming that the iPhone is connected to an Exchange server, is there any way to figure out whether MDM is enabled?

Comment: @lupincho There should be a message at the top of **Settings** along the lines of "This iPhone is supervised". Otherwise check in **Settings -> General -> VPN & Device Management**.